# html stored in javascript variable,how to Update that html inside javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here,

```
var data = '
<table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 100%;">    
    <tbody>     
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea cols="80" id="editor" name="editor" rows="10">This is my textarea to be replaced with Editor.</textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&copy; 2016 Vishmay Shah</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>'
```

I want to update the editor's id to editor1 using jquery within data variable

I can access it using

```
   $('#editor', Data)[0].id=$('#editor', Data)[0].id+'1';
```

but I want to save updated HTML in the data variable back.

**UPDATE**

There will be multiple editors with the same id editor.

Actually, I want to make it unique by appending index.

That is editor0,editor1,..., replace function will replace all editor, so it will not help

```
  var editors = $('#editor', Data);
    for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
        var subeditor = editors[i].id + i;
        editors[i].id = subeditor;
     }
```

Comment: try replace function

Comment: @Zan there may be multiple editor with same id editor, actually i want to make it unique by appending index-> that is editor0,editor1,..., replace function will replace all

Comment: _"there may be multiple editor with same id editor"_ `id` of element should be unique in document. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: @ guest271314 thats why i am replacing in var before loading in html

Comment: @VISHMAY _"thats why i am replacing"_ You could use same `className` and replacement would not be necessary ? Access element using bracket notation on DOM element `element[0]` , `element[1]` or jQuery `.eq()`; e.g; `$(".element").eq(0)`, `$(".element").eq(1)` to return same results as mutliple `id`s `$("#element0")` , ``$("#element1")``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one with the same ID name, perhaps you need to find it by attribute and replace the old ID name with index like so :

```
var Data = '<table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 100%;">    <tbody>     <tr><td><textarea cols="80" id="editor" name="editor" rows="10">This is my textarea to be replaced with Editor.</textarea><textarea cols="80" id="editor" name="editor" rows="10">This is my textarea to be replaced with Editor.</textarea></td>     </tr>       <tr>            <td colspan="2">&copy; 2016 Vishmay Shah</td>       </tr>   </tbody></table><p>&nbsp;</p>';
// this will look the element with ID editor
// and replace element with index
var newElem = $(Data).find('[id="editor"]').attr('id', function(i, old) {
     return old + i;
}).end();
console.log(newElem)
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/n37ra7r3/)*(inspect element to see the actual ID)*

Answer (score 0):

This will work out:

```
Data.replace('name="editor"','name="editor1"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating multiple elements `id` property can be achieved using `:last` , `.length` at `.prop(function(name, propertyValue){})` or `.attr(function(name, propertyValue){})`.

An alternative approach would be to try substituting using same `className` , e.g.; `.editor` , for multiple `id`s beginning with a name and ending in number at multiple elements. Use `.length` to determine which element currently being processed.